# why my custom server control does not maintain the viewstate information?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, custom-controls

i'm creating a custom server control. here is the related piece of custom control:

```
    public class ManagementUserControl : UserControl
    {
        GridView _grv;

        public ManagementUserControl()
        {
            _grv = new GridView();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// binds the grid to controls.
        /// </summary>
        public override void DataBind()
        {
            _grv.DataBind();
        }
        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
    //add controls only when is not postback
                InitializeGrid(); 
            }
        }
        void InitializeGrid()
        {
            this.Controls.Add(_grv);
        }
        [Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        public object DataSource
        {
            get { return _grv.DataSource; }
            set { _grv.DataSource = value; }
        }
    }
```

i'm adding the datasource object in code behind of Default.aspx like this:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            List<string> lst = new List<string>();
            lst.Add("test1");
            lst.Add("test2");
            lst.Add("test3");
            ucManagement.DataSource = lst;
            ucManagement.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

first, it works fine but when i postback the page the control is disapeared. so i checked the Conrols collection in Load event and saw that it's empty. worse than that is that grid.DataSource is null on postback!! 
why the viewstate of the gridview is not maintained and the datasource value is lost on postback? by the way the viewstate is not turned off anywhere in page or web.config file.

Comment: Some resources. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/893667   http://www.asp.net/web-forms/videos/how-do-i/how-do-i-save-and-load-view-state-information-for-a-custom-web-server-control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/945089.aspx/1) on the asp.net site. seems to be your exact scenario.